# Change dynamically a picture on a worksheet based on a value from a dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, dropdownlist

I use Windows 7 Professional and Excel 2013.

I would like to change dynamically a picture on a worksheet based on a value from a dropdown list. I found online 2 ways that seems to fit my problem. However, I can't  seem to make either of them work.

My dropdown list is located on my first worksheet named "Product Dashboard" in cell D20.
It refers to a list of bottle names in another worksheet called "Bottle" in cell: "A2:A50"
In the same worksheet  "Bottle" in cell: "K2:K50" I have a serie of bottle picture corresponding to the bottle names of A2:A50.
I would like to make the bottle picture corresponding to the value in the drop down list appear dynamically  approximatley around the L20:N26 area. See pictures.[Product dashboard worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG9By.jpg)[Bottle worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ulkG.jpg)

the 2 methods that I found online and can basically understand involve named range:
https://exceloffthegrid.com/automatically-change-picture/
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4025-excel-dynamic-image-in-cell.html

in Formula/new name, I tried to define a new range "Bottleimagelookup" referring to either one of these 2 formulas:

=INDEX(Table1[Picture],MATCH('Product Dashboard'!$D$20,+Table1[Bottle Name],0))

or

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2-1+MATCH('Product Dashboard'!$D$20,+Table1[Bottle Name], 0), 11))

However, each time, excel tells me: "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function ,etc.". See picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hCmy.png)

Do you know what is it that I am doing wrong? Would you know how to correct the formulas above or have a way that could solve my initial problem?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Why do you have the **`+`** before `Table1`in your `MATCH()` formulas? I don’t see it in either of the reference pages you cited, and it looks superfluous at best, and possibly irregular.  Try it without the **`+`**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did what you recommanded (I also replaced the "," in the formula by ";") and now the range is nmaed without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tested please change your formula to:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Picture],MATCH('Product Dashboard'!$D$20,Table1[Bottle Name],0))
```

or

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2-1+MATCH('Product Dashboard'!$D$20,Table1[Bottle Name], 0), 11))
```

Remove the `+` from your formulas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I did what you recommanded (I also replaced the "," in the formula by ";") and now the range is named without problem! 
So now I have a new range named "Bottleimagelookup".
However, a new problem appears.

After naming the range, I have to copy paste one of the picture where I want the relevant picture to appear. Then select the pasted picture and change the adress in the formula bar by the new named range ( in my case "Bottleimagelookup"). However, when I do so, Excel now tells me that the "Reference is not valid."
Do you know know what I did wrong?