# In Excel, how can I get use built in functions and/or write a VBA function to result in a picture being displayed as the formula result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1280047/change-dynamically-a-picture-on-a-worksheet-based-on-a-value-from-a-dropdown-lis), which got little attention.

Imagine that I have a workbook with images of all of the playing cards somewhere, like a lookup list. I want to randomly shuffle the deck (straightforward using random(), choose(), automatic recalculation off, and F9 to reshuffle) and then, say, display images of the first four cards dealt as the player's and dealer's initial Blackjack hands. For example, you might get images of an Ace of Diamonds and an Nine of Clubs, and you'd see the back of a card and an Ace of Hearts for the dealer's hand.

Ideas? (not on whether to hit or stand, but on how to show the images.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's probably not possible with built in functions. How to create a VBA function is a too broad question here, you need to show your efforts to do it and ask specific questions.  (If you don't know VBA then just hire somebody who knows)

Comment: Thank you. I do write VBA, clumsily; I'm a software developer and my main language is Java. I will look more deeply into how to approach this via VBA. I was hoping for a solution using just built-in functions, because people are (rightly) wary about opening Excel files with macros.